# How to match an option in a select element with substring?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below code matches a val in a select element and select the option in the code:

```
$("#modelListSelect option[val='" + modelMatch + "']").attr("selected", "true");
```

My select list values look like this:

```
["Washington 2015", "New York 1988", "Detroit 2000", "San Francisco 1999"];
```

This years in the list are dynamic and they can be different at a different time, for example:

```
["Washington 2011", "New York 1998", "Detroit 1975", "San Francisco 2016"];
```

All I want to do is matching the "val" above with a "modelMatch" such as "Detroit". So it will find "Detroit 2000" or "Detroit 1975"

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way..

you need to split the modelMatch value and get the matching substring as well.

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```js
var modelMatch = "Detroit 2001";
var res = modelMatch.split(" ")[0];
$("#modelListSelect option[value^='" + res + "']").attr("selected", "true");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="modelListSelect">
  <option value="Washington 2015">Washington 2015</option>
   <option value="New York 1988">New York 1988</option>
   <option value="Detroit 2000">Detroit 2000</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `val^='" + modelMatch + "']"` syntax to search for attributes starting with `modelMatch` string. You should also use the standard `value` attribute with option elements rather than `val`.

```js
modelMatch = "Detroit";
$("#modelListSelect option[value^='" + modelMatch + "']").attr('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="modelListSelect">
  <option value="Washington 2015">Washington 2015</option>
  <option value="New York 1988">New York 1988</option>
  <option value="Detroit 2000">Detroit 2000</option>
  <option value="San Francisco 1999">San Francisco 1999</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery [Attribute Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

The HTML:

```
<select id="foo">
  <option value="Washington 2017">Washington 2017</option>
  <option value="Detroit 2016">Detroit 2016</option>
  <option value="San Francisco 2015">San Francisco 2015</option>
</select>
```

And the jQuery code:

```
$("#foo option[value^='Detroit']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yhvLp0gn/2/) with an example.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful for you....

```
<select id="ddlListSelect">
  <option value="Washington 2015">Washington 2015</option>
   <option value="New York 1988">New York 1988</option>
   <option value="Detroit 2000">Detroit 2000</option>
  </select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {     

        var ddlText = "Detroit 2001";
        var str = ddlText.substr(0, ddlText.indexOf(' '));;
        $("#ddlListSelect option[value^='" + str + "']").attr("selected", "true");

    });
</script>
```